# Enabling RetryListenerSupport breaks @Retryable methods

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface with parameters I apply to a bunch of methods in a wrapper class

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3,
            listeners = {"springRetryLoggingListener"},
            value = { AmazonClientException.class }, 
            backoff = @Backoff(
                    delay = 1000, 
                    multiplier = 2))
public @interface AWSS3Retryable {}
```

I want to add a listener that will log when a retry occurs. I create this bean, and from the config above I am referencing it.

```
@Component
public class SpringRetryLoggingListener extends RetryListenerSupport {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringRetryLoggingListener.class);

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        LOG.warn("Retryable method {} threw {}th exception {}", context.getAttribute("context.name"), context.getRetryCount(), throwable.toString());
        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I do this, the retry stops occurring. Even if I don't reference the bean in the @Retryable block it doesn't work. It appears that even having a RetryListenerSupport bean loaded by spring it won't work.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks